# Error: no jzmq in java.library.path

Tags: java, zeromq, jzmq

I installed zmq using homebrew and then installed jzmq from the github master.

I am getting this error:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jzmq in java.library.path
```

I tried setting the path:

```
System.setProperty("java.library.path","/usr/local/lib")
```

These files are in `/usr/local/lib`

```
libzmq.a
libzmq.dylib
libzmq.la
libjzmq.a
libjzmq.dylib
libjzmq.la
```

Comment: Not really a solution but I switched to using the more performant Scala bindings.. then I dumped ZMQ.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem on *Linux (eclipse)*, I solved it out by setting up the path of **native library jzmq** for my **zmq.jar**. By going into the project properties ( right click on `project -> Properties... -> Java Build Path` ), you can then add the *JDIC.jar* as a library on the library tab, expand it, and edit the *Native Library* Location property to point to the folder containing the native libraries: In my case it was `/usr/local/lib`.

So, basically, you could add `-Djava.library.path` as a VM argument in the launch configuration or set the native library as specified in 
http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t49342.html

Have a good day.

Comment: Duplicate answer posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51788924