# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jzmq in java.library.path in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, zeromq, publish-subscribe, jzmq

Import org.zeromq.ZMQ;

-For the above import statement, I am using "org folder" in jzmq master folder  which consists of ZMQ.java file.

-So, there is no problem with compilation. When I start running the program, It shows below exception

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jzmq in java.library.path
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
        at org.zeromq.ZMQ.(ZMQ.java:41)
        at server.main(Server.java:13)

What should I have to do? 
Which packages I have to download and which import statements I have to use for the ZeroMQ helloworld example in java?

I saw that many people are using libzmq.dll, jzmq.dll and some jar files somewhere to avoid that exception. But I want a clear answer.

Answer (score 3):

This lib (jzmq) is binding to the native library libzmq.
If you don't use features of libzmq (ipc for example) you'd better to use full java implementation - **jeromq** ([mvnrepo](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.zeromq/jeromq), [jeromq git](https://github.com/zeromq/jeromq)). It has almost the same functionality.

Otherwise if you need jzmq, you have to compile it properly.
This is the way i compiled it on windows x64:

To build the library you need IDE Visual Studio 2010 or higher. In this example i used 2013 version. All work is performed in the directory `C:\zmq` (for example).

1. Get the zeromq, jzmq and libsodium-1.0.10 sources.
2. Copy the entire contents of zeromq directory to `C:\zmq`.
3. Create a directory `C:\zmq\java`.
4. Copy the entire contents of jzmq directory to `C:\zmq\java`.
5. Create a directories `C:\zmq\libsodium` and `C:\zmq\libsodium`
6. Copy to `C:\zmq\libsodium\bi`n `libsodium-1.0.10-msvc\Win32` and
   `libsodium-1.0.10-msvc\x64` directories.
7. Create a directory `C:\zmq\libsodium\src`.
8. Copy to `C:\zmq\libsodium\src directory`
   libsodium-1.0.10-msvc\include.

**Zeromq.**

Open in Visual Studio the appropriate zeromq solution file from the directory `C:\zmq\builds\msvc`.

Open configuration manager. Active configuration solutions - choose DynRelease. Active solution platform - choose x64.

Open project properties page, go to Configuration Properties - C/C++ - General, check paths for include files directories.

Then select linker - General, and check paths for the libraries directories.

In the configuration file `C:\zmq\builds\msvc\vs2013\libsodium.import.props` correct path in the  section.

Then buid it, if all was correct you will get dlls in `C:\zmq\bin\x64\Release\v120\dynamic` directory. If it wasn't - check out logs, make changes and rebuild it.

---

**Jzmq.**

Now open the appropriate jzmq solution file from the directory `C:\zmq\java\builds\msvc\`

As well as in zeromq project open configuration manager and select Release and x64 platform.

Open project properties page, go to Configuration Properties - VC ++ Directories and check that path where your JDK was installed is correct.
You will se there something like this:

```
..\..\..\..\include;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_71\include;C:\Program
Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_71\include\win32;$(IncludePath)
```

Also check that Library Catalogues (forgot its name) path include path to the directory with built zeromq libs.
It will look like this:

```
..\..\..\..\bin\x64\Release\v120\dynamic;$(LibraryPath)
```

On the properties page, go to Configuration Properties - assembly events - event before assembly and check property "Command Prompt" (first of all check paths to files in copy command).
It will look like this:

```
copy ..\config.hpp &quot;..\..\..\src\main\c++\&quot;
```

Then buid jzmq, if all was correct you will get files in `C:\zmq\java\lib`.

If it wasn't - check out logs, make changes and rebuild it.

---

In the `C:\zmq` you need only bin `java\lib` directories, the rest can be removed.

Add to PATH the path to `bin\x64\Release\v120\dynamic` and run you java app with `-Djava.library.path="path_to_java\lib"`

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by setting up the path of the native library `jzmq` for my `zmq.jar`. Go into the project properties ( right click on project -> Properties... -> Java Build Path ), you can then add the `JDIC.jar` as a library on the library tab, expand it, and edit the Native Library Location property to point to the folder containing the native libraries:in my case it was `/usr/local/lib`.

So, basically, you could add `-Djava.library.path` as a VM argument in the launch configuration or set the native library as specified in [this forum post](http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t49342.html).