# Can't load jzmq.dll into java

Tags: java, dll, java-native-interface

I want to run zmq with java.
I had tried to do it like in a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40436312/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-no-jzmq-in-java-libra?answertab=votes#tab-top)

I compiled project https://github.com/zeromq/libzmq then https://github.com/zeromq/jzmq

After all run my program with argument `-Djava.library.path=C:\zmq\jzmq\jzmq-jni\builds\msvc\x64\Release\;C:\zmq\libzmq\bin\x64\Release\v141\dynamic`

```
import org.zeromq.ZMQ;

public class TestZMQ {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ZMQ.Context context = ZMQ.context(1);
    }
}
```

As a result I have exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\zmq\jzmq\jzmq-jni\builds\msvc\x64\Release\jzmq.dll: Can't find dependent libraries
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1941)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1857)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
    at org.zeromq.ZMQ.<clinit>(ZMQ.java:40)
    at TestZMQ.main(TestZMQ.java:8)
```

[Dependency walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) shows multiple errors. People says it appear because of walker own, not library.
[image]

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you unfold `ADVAPI32.DLL`, showing the other direct dependencies of `JZMQ.DLL` and `LIBZMQ.DLL`?

Comment: @manuell, thank you for your interest. My solution below.

Answer (score 1):

There is the problem with `java.library.path` in windows. Normally it takes system var `Path` and put it into `java.library.path`. 
When I set `-Djava.library.path=myLybraryPath`, it became `myLybraryPath`, but you need something like this `${java.library.path};myLybraryPath`otherwise your application can't find windows libs.

I've found the solution of this problem by adding my library in `Path's` system variable.  [There is another similar solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661320/how-to-add-native-library-to-java-library-path-with-eclipse-launch-instead-of)

`set PATH=%PATH%;myLybraryPath`

PS: There is no the same problem in linux. It's just windows'  [jvm](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html)  realization problem.

Comment: I think your answer is wrong. Java doesn't "overwrites system variable".

Comment: @mauell yor are right. Of course it's not. I corrected my answer